# Doctrine 1.2: events with out-of-date invokers cause problem with versionable behaviour

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I have a feeling there might be something I am missing here, but here I go anyway.

Consider this: I have a 'Booking' class that has a user_id field and the Versionable behaviour and I run the following code:

```
$booking = new Booking();

$booking->user_id = 1;

$booking->isValid();

$booking->user_id = 2;

$booking->save();
```

This results in the correct record being inserted into the 'booking' table.  BUT the record that is inserted into 'booking_version' table is out of date!  The user_id is set to 1 because the data is pulled off the event invoker that was created during the first isValid() call.  Furthermore, the id field is set to 0 for the same reason (which means the version record cannot be linked back to the booking)

I can get around this problem by calling $booking->clearInvokedSaveHooks() before the save(), but I dont really want to do this because I dont want to run all my save hooks again on saving.

Is there a better way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to workaround here. `Versionable` behaviour is [designed to store **previous** values](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/behaviors/en#core-behaviors%3aversionable) of the record.

If you want to store every single temporary state of the object - you'll have to `save` it each time.

Comment: I dont actually want to store every temporary state.  I want the BookingVersion to store the 'final' state of the Booking when I call save() regardless of how the Booking's values have been changed since I instantiated it.  Unfortunatelly It appears as if when I change a specific variable on the Booking more than once between instantiating it and saving it, then the versionable behaviour breaks.

Comment: What do you mean by `final` state? If you wan your changes discraded - just don't save them. If you want all your changes persisted in only one record - just save the object, it's the default behavior. If you want only single copy of your object in booking_version... Why do you need it? So, your intention is a bit unclear, could you clarify it?